# Application Load Balancer https request to EC2 nodejs running on port 4000

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, load-balancing

I have an Application Load Balancer that is in HTTPS and will make a request to my EC2 instance. I have configured the ALB listeners to HTTP/HTTPS and then I have specified the target group (for the application load balancer) as the EC2 instance.

On this EC2 instance, I have two things running: 1) A website 2) A nodejs service (on port 4000)

In the target group I have specified the relevant EC2 instance twice. (once with port number 80 and another with port number 4000). On port 4000, the health check seems to be failing (even though the service is running on port 4000 only).[image: screenshot attached for reference]

When I make the htttps request to my website, the response is fine. However, when I make the https request to my nodejs service (running on port number 4000), it is giving connection refused error.

Comment: Hi, why did you register twice? How is the differentiation for you? Anything in this target group could be routed to, so it will be trying to distribute traffic between the instance twice running on different ports :)

Answer (score 0):

A target group should only be forwarding to one application. So you would want a separate target group for your web site and your node js service. Then using ALB use [advanced routing](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-advanced-request-routing-for-aws-application-load-balancers/) to determine which to load.

An example of above would be:

- Path of /api/* forwards to node js target group
- Default forwards to website.

Secondly your health check must pass on your node js app, its currently returning a 404 indicating that the path you are host checking against is not available.

Finally make sure you connect based on the listener configuration (http/https and port), not the port from the target group.

Comment: Hi Mokugo. Thank you for response. So my website is deployed on the following hostname: http://taboo-game.com/

And my nodejs service is running on port number 4000. However, when I try to access it using taboo-game.com:4000/category 
It is failing. However, it works perfectly when I directly put in the IP address of the EC2 instance rather than taboo-game.com

Comment: Can you check the following, that the target group with the nodejs service is showing the targets as healthy, the listener for the target group is using port 4000 and that the security group on the load balancer is allowing inbound access on port 4000

Comment: Just did all the steps once again.
thanks a lot Mokugo!!! You are a lifesaver.